# Ansible building dynamic lists

Tags: list, ansible

I'm struggling with syntax to build and add to list dynamically. Would like to do it in an ansible line without going to a jinja2 template. I've been messing around while but the below is where I started. The error is in the line to set the fact.

```
- name: Assign data to the correct list based on the meta value.
  set_fact:
    "{{ next_reference.list_name }}": "{{ next_reference.list_name|default([]) + [ input_data ] }}"
  loop: "{{ reference_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: next_reference
  when: input_data.meta == next_reference.meta

reference_list:
  - meta: "test1"
    list_name: "test1_list"
  - meta: "test2"
    list_name: "test2_list"
  - meta: "test3"
    list_name: "test3_list"

input_data_list:
  - meta: "anp"
    value1: "one"
    value2: "two"
```

Thanks for any assistance may have to go the jinja2 route in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. This issue was a reminder that jinja2 and ansible are simple tools not programming languages so the key is to think simplistically.

If you want to change data in a list of dictionaries. The best way to do it is trawl through the current list and pull out the data from the dictionary you want to create a new dictionary put the new data in it or amend it. Stick this new dictionary in a list.
Use rejectattr to remove the dictionary from the current list. Use a simple jinja2 template to recombine the new and old list.

Answer (score 0):

Without Jinja, it's not possible to indirectly declare or modify variables in Ansible. Instead, an appropriate data structure might serve the purpose, e.g.

```yaml
    t:
      t1: "{{ test1_list|default([]) }} + {{ input_data }}"
      t2: "{{ test2_list|default([]) }} + {{ input_data }}"
      t3: "{{ test3_list|default([]) }} + {{ input_data }}"
```